# getting error during select data from two table

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

```
Error Number: 1096
```

No tables used
SELECT *

```
$where = array();
            if($category){
                $where[] = 'subcategories.categories_id = '.$category;
            }
            if($value){
                $where[] = "subcategories.name LIKE '%".$value."%'";
            }
            $where = implode('and', $where);
            $this->db->query("select subcategories.*, categories.name as catname FROM subcategories JOIN categories ON categories.id = subcategories.categories_id where ".$where);
            $query = $this->db->get();
```

I am joining two table category and subcategory with dynamic where condition.same query working in phpmyadmin but getting error in codeigniter , thanks in advance

Comment: For custom queries like `$this->db->query('....')` you should not call  `$this->db->get()` it will not work for custom queries

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try like

```
$query = $this->db->query("Your Query Here");
$query = $query->result();
print_r($query);
```

And Edit your where condition like

```
$where = '';
if($category){
     $where .= 'subcategories.categories_id = '.$category;
}
if($value){
     if($category) {
         $where .= " AND ";
     }
     $where .= "subcategories.name LIKE '%".$value."%'";
}
```

Comment: thax for the help but its solve problem with using this $query = $query->result();

Answer (score 2):

Please try to follow codeigniter's conventions.
Here is your solution as per your requirement:

```
$this->db->select('subcategories.*, categories.name as catname');
$this->db->from('subcategories');
$this->db->join('categories', 'categories.id = subcategories.categories_id');
if($category)
{
    $this->db->where('subcategories.categories_id', $category); 
}
if($value)
{
    $this->db->like('subcategories.name', $value,'both'); 
}
$query = $this->db->get()->result();
```

Answer (score 0):

you can follow **codeigniter** conventions to prepare SQL query

Try this way,

```
$this->db->select("subcategories.*, categories.name as catname", false)
            ->join("categories", "categories.id = subcategories.categories_id")
                ->where("subcategories.categories_id", $category)
                    ->like("subcategories.name", $value, "both");
$query = $this->db->get("subcategories")->result();
```